# React Native iOS high CPU usage

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I originally produced a react-native app for Android and I've recently been porting this top run on iOS.

When I profile my app on Android the CPU usage is somewhere around 10-15% which is pretty good.

Profiling the same app on iOS and the CPU usage is really high at 90%+ and some usage it's peaking at 135%.

I don't have that much experience with Xcode and I'm finding it hard to figure out why the CPU usage is so high.

Can anyone give me any pointers on what to look for or to figure out what's causing the high usage.